# php for google analytics api (get referred from) using gapi

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I am trying to request (using the gapi source code) the referred from  link to the users website. so for example if they clicked through from facebook, and how many referrals came through.

My gapi code to link for page view by date currently looks like this.

```
$ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);
$filter = 'country == United Kingdom && browser == Firefox || browser == Chrome';
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('browser','browserVersion'),array('pageviews','visits'),'-visits',$filter,  $start_date=$date, $end_date=$date);
```

and is echoed in the page with

```
<?php echo $ga->getVisits() ?>
```

How do i get the filter to display the refered from in a list nd echo it through the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my script that sole purpose is to get referral URL and total pageviews and visits. I think that's what you want.

```
<?php
define('ga_email','username@email.com');
define('ga_password','password');
define('ga_profile_id','profile_id');

require 'gapi.class.php';

$ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);

$filter = 'medium==referral && referralPath != /';

/***  // << add '/' to uncomment
$date_start = '2011-11-01';
$date_end = '2011-11-13';
//**/$date_start = $date_end = null;

$ga->requestReportData(
    ga_profile_id,
    array('source','referralPath'),//what field you are looking for
    array('pageviews','visits'),//what metric you want to calculate
    '-visits',//sort order, prefix - means descending
    $filter,//filter query
    $date_start,//yyyy-mm-dd or null
    $date_end,//yyyy-mm-dd or null
    1,//offset lookup
    100);//max result
?>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Referral URL</th>
  <th>Pageviews</th>
  <th>Visits</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result):
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $result->getSource() . $result->getReferralPath() ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $result->getPageviews() ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $result->getVisits() ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
endforeach
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks I have been trying to do this for a while!  Awesome

Comment: This is great but do you know how to make is show the top referrals for a particular page?  I am trying top show my top referrals for each blog post on a wordpress site? I tried changing my filter to this... `$filter = 'pagePath==/articles/50-web-developer-documentation-manuals-you-need-to-know-about/ && medium==referral && referralPath != /';` but it seemed to only show a handful of results when I did this which can't be accurate!